# Performing some arithmetic operations inside a MySQL query on a subset of records

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a MySQL table containing attendance records. Relevant columns identify attendees, sessions and attendance status (confirmed/declined/no-response). I also have a second table containing attendees' personal info, including the date they joined the group.

I am trying to build a single query that will output a list of all attendees, the number of times they attended sessions, and their regularity, expressed as the percentage of sessions they attended (against the total number of sessions). The problem is that total of sessions should only contains the sessions since the attendee joined the group.

So, for the first part, my query is:

```
SELECT name, count(*)
FROM attendance, members
WHERE attendance.attend = 2 and
      attendance.member_number = members.number
GROUP BY attendance.member_number, attendance.attend
HAVING count(*) > 0
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

This returns all attendees' names, plus the number of sessions each had attended. However, I'd also like to add that third column.

Thus, for each record, I first have to find out what was the members.member_since date, then query only the group of attendance records for each member, for which the dates are greater than member_since, get their count, then from that subset get the count where atteneance.attend = 2, then calculate what percentage of that subset count represents the second count (of records having attend = 2).

How do I write my query?

Data looks like this:

Table members:

```
number, name, join_date
001, Peter James, 2016-07-26
002, John Smith, 2014-06-04
```

TABLE attendance:

```
member_number, attend, date
001, 2, 2019-05-11
001, 1, 2019-05-04
001, 2, 2019-04-26
001, 2, 2019-04-18
002, 2, 2014-08-01
002, 1, 2016-08-01
002, 1, 2019-05-04
```

The desired result would be to get the following:

```
Name, Attended, percentage
Peter James, 3, 75%
John Smith, 1, 14%
```

In other words, while there were 6 sessions, Peter James has only been member for the last four, and attended 3 of them (75%), while John Smith has been a member since the beginning, so his attendance is one out of 6.

The structure is somewhat simplified (there is a 'sessions' table with details about sessions, including the date, and the 'attendance' table refers to its key column, 'att_number', rather than the actual date), but the point is the same.

Comment: There's no need for `HAVING COUNT(*) > 0`. If the count is zero they won't be returned by the `JOIN`.

Comment: Do you have another table that lists all the sessions with the session dates?

Comment: How do you tell how many different sessions there are? You're saying there are a total of 6 sessions, but what if two members attend the same session? That would create 7 rows, but still only 6 sessions.

Comment: Yes; the 'Attendance' table only contains attendance records, so several may be for the same session but different members. Same sessions are identified by date. My sample data was a bit too simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables just on the dates to get the total number of sessions since the member joined. Then use a conditional `SUM()` to get the number of sessions that the member attended. Divide them to get the percentage.

```
SELECT m.name, SUM(m.number = a.member_number AND a.attend = 2) AS attendance, 100*SUM(m.number = a.member_number AND a.attend = 2)/COUNT(*) AS percent
FROM members AS m
JOIN attendance AS a ON a.date >= m.member_since
GROUP BY m.number
ORDER BY attendance DESC
```

Comment: That works, but now I'll need to expand that join to resolve the actual date. For simplicity, I had moved it to the 'attendance' table, but it is indeed in another table with extra session info.

Thanks very much for helping with this, it is already enough!

Comment: This formatting is tragic; an affront to aesthetics. I want to downvote. I think I shall.

Comment: Feel free, I need some downvotes to keep me humble.